# Why do I have two datagrids in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I don't understand why I have a duplicate of columns how can I remove the 3 last columns. I have tried to fix it but everytime I remove all the columns.

Here is how I populate the datagrid.

```
 protected void BindGridList()
    {
       DataTable dt = ConvertToDatatable(lEmp);

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv = dt.DefaultView;

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dt.Columns.Count;
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "datos no encontrados";
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        }
 }
```

Here is a what my grid looks like visually.
[image: Duplicate table columns]

Comment: Do you have both TemplateField and AutoGenerated columns perhaps?

Comment: Yes thank you by default AutoGenerateColumns="true" so I add  AutoGenerateColumns="false" it fixed the issue. I didn't know that.